# create a script to classify elements of a CSV file

Tags: csv

I have the list of all the airports in the world in a CSV file. I would like if it is possible to create a script which allows to create a folder (name of the country) and to put all the airports of the same country in the same folder and to do this automatically for all the countries present in the CSV files.
Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am assuming that you have a csv file called **input.csv** which contains a column named **Country**
The following python script creates a folder for every distinct country in the input file and appends the airport data in a file called data.csv inside that folder.

```
import os
import csv

countries = []

with open('input.csv', 'r') as read_obj:
  csv_dict_reader = csv.DictReader(read_obj)
  for row in csv_dict_reader:
    if row["Country"] not in countries:
      countries.append(row["Country"])
      try:
        os.mkdir(row["Country"])
      except FileExistsError:
        print(row["Country"],  " already exists")
    with open(row["Country"] + '/data.csv', 'a+') as f:
      writer = csv.DictWriter(f, row.keys())
      writer.writerow(row)
```

You might want to check **pandas** for another way to achieve this.

The following script reads 2 different csv files containting data the reference the same airport codes, creates a folder for each airport code and saves it's data in 2 different files: one for each input. Change the output and input filenames according to your needs.

```
import os
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.read_csv('input.csv')
df2 = pd.read_csv('input1.csv')

for c in df1['code'].unique():
   try:
       os.mkdir(c)
   except FileExistsError:
       print(c,  " already exists")
   df1.loc[df1["code"] == c].to_csv(c + '/output1.csv', index=False)

for c in df2['code'].unique():
   try:
       os.mkdir(c)
   except FileExistsError:
       print(c,  " already exists")
   df2.loc[df2["code"] == c].to_csv(c + '/output2.csv', index=False)
```

Comment: thank you very much, it works. I need a new script which will create a folder for each airport. Each airport has a code (for example: EGLL). The data comes from two different CSVs. It is therefore necessary that all the data which belong to the same airport is in the same file, the file will have as name the code of this one.

Comment: I actually have 2 CSVs
-> Runway
-> frequencies
In these files, the airports are not referenced by country but by code.
So it is necessary that the script can put in a folder (code name of the airport), the data of the same airport coming from the two files.

Comment: exactly, the two files have different columns but they have the same "airport_ident" column

Comment: I would like the script to create the folder and in it there will be the two csv frequencies and runways. but they will have the data only from the airport of the current folder.

Comment: this error means that you are trying to create a folder using a float number as a name. replace mkdir(c) with mkdir(str(c))

Comment: I've an other error File "CSV_airportsDataSort.py", line 12, in <module> df1.loc[df1["airport_ident"] == c].to_csv(c + '/Runways.csv', index=False) TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'float' and 'str'

Comment: This a type error. you need to cast your values to the appropriate type like before.

Comment: last thing, now I have a file with all the countries and another file with all the airports in the world. I would need a script that allows you to move the airport files to their country file. for example all canadian airports will have to go in the CA folder. therefore in each country file there is a CSV of all the airports in the country. So for each airport code you have to move the code folder in the country folder. For example EGLL is in the UK airport list so the EGLL folder goes in the UK country folder.

Comment: please help me !